# How do I declare constructors for classes I inherit from?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class TableServiceEntity
{
    protected TableServiceEntity();
    protected TableServiceEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey);
    .....
    .....
}
```

I inherit from this class as follows:

```
public class AuditableTableServiceEntity : TableServiceEntity  
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    .....
    .....
}
```

I use the class as follows:

```
public class Note : AuditableTableServiceEntity
{

    public Note() { }
    public Note(string dsValue, string pk)
        : base(pk, Seq.GetNext(dsValue, pk, "Note").ToString("00000")) { }
```

It fails saying that the class AuditableTableServiceEntity does not have a constructor that
takes two arguments. To fix I tried to add the following methods to AuditableTableServiceEntity. Is this a valid thing to do or is there some other way? Also I notice it requires me to add a constructor that takes zero arguments. Why is that?

```
    public AuditableTableServiceEntity()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public AuditableTableServiceEntity(string pk, string rk)
        : base(pk, rk) 
    { 
    }
```

Can someone give me advice as to if I'm on the right track or if there is some better way of doing this. Should I declare the methods on AuditableTableServiceEntity as protected and also should I declare that class as abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone give me advice as to if I'm on the right track or if there is some better way of doing this.

This is the correct approach.

> Should I declare the methods on AuditableTableServiceEntity as protected and also should I declare that class as abstract?

It depends.  Should the user be able to directly construct an instance of an `AuditableTableServiceEntity`?  If so, then the constructors should be public, and the class should not be abstract.

If, however, it doesn't make sense, and the user should always construct a `Note` or other similar class, then protected constructors and an abstract class is appropriate.

Comment: The user should not be able to directly construct an instance of AuditableTableServiceEntity. So should I make the constructors protected and the class abstract and properties virtual? thanks

Comment: @Melissa If you don't want the user to construct it, I'd make the constructors protected and the class abstract.  Whether or not the properties should be virtual is a separate issue...